# Using string parameter in bash script failt

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, keytool

I need to create a few certificates and wanted to write a small bash script for this.

First of all, I don't have much experience with creating my own bash scripts.

I wanted to pass the most important values like computer name and password as parameters. Unfortunately I get the error:

> keytool error :java.io.IoException:Incorrect AVA format

The error indicates that the strings in the commands are not interpreted correctly.
I think the problem is that I am not working properly with the strings, but I don't understand exactly what is wrong.

If I enter the command like this in the terminal it works fine

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$1" # servername
echo "$2" # domain
echo "$3" # password
echo

keytool -noprompt -keystore $1.$2.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca.cert -storetype jks -storepass $3 -keypass $3

keytool -genkey -noprompt -keyalg RSA -storetype pkcs12 -alias $1.$2 -dname $1'.'$2',O=COMPANY,OU=COMPANY,L=NY,ST=NY,C=us' \
      -ext 'SAN=DNS:example1.com,DNS:example2.com'
      -keystore $1.$2'.keystore2.jks' -storepass $3 -keypass $3
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Any spaces or globbing wildcards (`*`, `?`, `[...]`) in your password value? Not quoting the parameter expansion will cause those wildcards to be evaluated and expanded to multiple paths and the expanded value will be split by whitespace.

Comment: yes, i use two special chars ! and #

Comment: `!` could trigger history expansion in bash (which is what you are using, even though your script doesn't require a bash and would work with `sh` just fine)

Comment: OK, but I can't change the password.

Comment: @knittl but it can't actually be the password. it also works manually in the terminal.

Comment: @knittl : History expansion is by default turned off in a script and we can see that it hasn't been turned on.

Comment: You didn't show how you invoke your script. Aside from this, turning on the -x option helps for debugging.

Comment: @user1934428
when i try to use -x
`Ungültige Option:  -x
keytool -genkeypair [OPTION]...`

Comment: @user1934428
so i use the command manual in the terminal and its works fine!
`keytool -genkey -noprompt \
      -keyalg RSA \
      -storetype pkcs12 \
      -alias server.example.com \
      -dname 'CN=server.example.com,O=COMPANY,OU=COMPANY,L=NY,ST=NY,C=US' \
   -ext "SAN=DNS:example.com, DNS:example2.com" \
   -keystore server.example.com.keystore.jks \
   -storepass 'passwort!#' \
   -keypass 'passwort!#'`

Comment: This is nice to hear, but not what I asked .... AND you did not show HOW you exeactly turned on `-x`.

Comment: For turning on tracing, you either put a `set -x` into your script, or run it with `bash -x SCRIPTNAME ...`.

Comment: You're missing a backslash from the end of the line `-ext 'SAN=DNS:example1.com,DNS:example2.com'` so `-keystore $1.$2'.keystore2.jks' -storepass $3 -keypass $3` is a separate command from the lines above it. As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at shellcheck.net before posting them here.". There are several other issues with your code that shellcheck could also tell you about. If you still have a problem after correcting those, let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using correct quoting, correct escaping of end of line, and adding the missing `CN=` to the `-dname` option string.:

```
keytool -genkey -noprompt -keyalg RSA -storetype pkcs12 -alias "$1.$2" \
      -dname "CN=$1.$2,O=COMPANY,OU=COMPANY,L=NY,ST=NY,C=us" \
      -ext 'SAN=DNS:example1.com,DNS:example2.com' \
      -keystore "$1.$2.keystore2.jks" -storepass "$3" -keypass "$3"
```

Investigation details and observations below...

You tell us [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77451465/using-string-parameter-in-bash-script-failt/77455806#comment136543099_77451535) that this works:

```
server_name="$1"
domain="$2"
password="$3"

keytool -noprompt -keystore "$server_name.$domain.truststore.jks" -alias CARoot -import -file ca.cert -storetype jks -storepass "$password" -keypass "$password"
```

and [you tell us in another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77451465/using-string-parameter-in-bash-script-failt/77455806#comment136544828_77451465) that this works:

```
keytool -genkey -noprompt \
-keyalg RSA \
-storetype pkcs12 \
-alias server.example.com \
-dname 'CN=server.example.com,O=COMPANY,OU=COMPANY,L=NY,ST=NY,C=US' \
-ext "SAN=DNS:example.com, DNS:example2.com" \
-keystore server.example.com.keystore.jks \
-storepass 'passwort!#' \
-keypass 'passwort!#'
```

If that 2nd script above with hard-coded values works then this one using variables for the options we'll later populate from script arguments must also work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

the_alias='server.example.com'
the_dname='CN=server.example.com,O=COMPANY,OU=COMPANY,L=NY,ST=NY,C=US'
the_keystore='server.example.com.keystore.jks'
the_pass='passwort!#'

keytool -genkey -noprompt \
-keyalg RSA \
-storetype pkcs12 \
-alias "$the_alias" \
-dname "$the_dname" \
-ext 'SAN=DNS:example.com, DNS:example2.com' \
-keystore "$the_keystore" \
-storepass "$the_pass" \
-keypass "$the_pass"
```

If that works, then we just need to map the values being used as options in the command that does not work (copied from your question and laid out one per line for comparison with the other scripts I'm using and with the missing escape fixed):

```
keytool -genkey -noprompt \
-keyalg RSA \
-storetype pkcs12 \
-alias $1.$2 \
-dname $1'.'$2',O=COMPANY,OU=COMPANY,L=NY,ST=NY,C=us' \
-ext 'SAN=DNS:example1.com,DNS:example2.com' \
-keystore $1.$2'.keystore2.jks' \
-storepass $3 \
-keypass $3
```

to populate the variables we introduced from the arguments passed to your script instead of hard-coding them and then this must work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

the_alias="$1.$2"
the_dname="CN=${the_alias},O=COMPANY,OU=COMPANY,L=NY,ST=NY,C=us"
the_keystore="${the_alias}.keystore.jks"
the_pass="$3"

keytool -genkey -noprompt \
-keyalg RSA \
-storetype pkcs12 \
-alias "$the_alias" \
-dname "$the_dname" \
-ext 'SAN=DNS:example.com, DNS:example2.com' \
-keystore "$the_keystore" \
-storepass "$the_pass" \
-keypass "$the_pass"
```

where you call the above as:

```
./the_script 'server' 'example.com' 'passwort!#'
```

So - does that work or not? If not, which of the above 2 scripts I provided fail?

While doing that coding I noticed that, in addition to the missing quotes and missing backslash at the end of the `-ext` line in the failing script:

- The version of the code you say worked uses `keystore.jks` while the version you say does not work uses `keystore2.jks` (note the `2`)
- Similarly for `SAN=DNS:example.com` vs `SAN=DNS:example1.com` (note
  the `1`).
- The blank character after `,` is only present in the working `-ext`
  option string.
- The `-dname` option in your working script starts
  with `CN=` while in the failing one it does not.

Are any of those a problem?

Comment: Great, now it works,

I must have lost the DN during the constant editing.

Many thanks for your detailed reply.

Answer (score -1):

It's the way you're handling spaces and concatenating strings. When passing parameters in a script, u need to properly quote variables to handle cases where values contain spaces.

Try this modified version of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
server_name="$1"
domain="$2"
password="$3"
echo "$server_name"
echo "$domain"
echo "$password"
keytool -noprompt -keystore "$server_name.$domain.truststore.jks" -alias CARoot -import -file ca.cert -storetype jks -storepass "$password" -keypass "$password"
keytool -genkey -noprompt -keyalg RSA -storetype pkcs12 -alias "$server_name.$domain" -dname "$server_name.$domain,O=COMPANY,OU=COMPANY,L=NY,ST=NY,C=us" \
      -ext "SAN=DNS:example1.com,DNS:example2.com" -keystore "$server_name.$domain.keystore2.jks" -storepass "$password" -keypass "$password"
```

This script properly quotes variables and ensures that filenames and values with spaces are handled correctly. Do try it out!

Comment: I understand what you mean. I have rebuilt it but unfortunately the error remains.
the first command works. only with the second command does the error occur.

Comment: It looks to me as if the bash omits the " when it executes the command.

Comment: It seems like the issue might be related to the way you're handling the Distinguished Name (DN) in the second keytool command. It could be the spaces in the DN that could be causing problems.

Comment: keytool -genkey -noprompt -keyalg RSA -storetype pkcs12 -alias "$server_name.$domain" \
       -dname "CN=$server_name.$domain, O=COMPANY, OU=COMPANY, L=NY, ST=NY, C=us" \
       -ext "SAN=DNS:example1.com,DNS:example2.com" \
       -keystore "$server_name.$domain.keystore2.jks" -storepass "$password" -keypass "$password"

Comment: @Husker `"` are not part of the value, but part of the shell syntax. If you require quotes to be part of the value, you must either write `"\"...\""` or `'"..."'`.

Comment: @knittl
I thought about that too...
but when I add "\" in front and behind I get the following error: 
Keytool-Fehler: java.io.IOException: Invalid keyword ""SERVER.EXAMPLE.COM,O"

Comment: @Vinith_jk_bro i cant find any spaces, Your code does not work either.